# Duplicating columns from parent to child model. Good or bad practice?

Tags: mysql, sql, laravel, optimization

I have a parent model **Post** and a child model **Comment**. Posts have privacy setting - column `privacy` in the DB. Any time when I have to deal with a child model **Comment** I have to check privacy settings if the parent model: `$comment->post->privacy`.

My app is becoming bigger and bigger and such approach needs more and more SQL-requests. Eager loading helps, but sometimes there is no other reasons to touch the parent model except of checking the privacy field.

My question is: Is it a good practice to duplicate the privacy column into the **Posts** table and keep them in sync? It will allow me to simply use `$comment->privacy` without touching the **Posts** table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Planned redundancy (denormalization of the model) for a specific purpose can be good.

You specifically mention keeping the `privacy` column on the child table "in sync" with the `privacy` column in the parent table. That implies you have control of the redundancy. That's acceptable practice, especially for improved performance.

If it doesn't improve performance, then there wouldn't really be a need.

Uncontrolled redundancy can be bad.

Comment: Thank you very much, @spencer7593. It was hard for me to formulate my question, but now I know, that it's called "denormalization". I've read some more theoretical information about this problem and came to the conclusion that in my case it's too early to denormalize my DB :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the privacy properties have to be in the parent (if the "Post" are not used directly on its own you can always move the property "privacy" to all the children)
**First** you should try enhance the performance using optimization techniques (like indexes, materialized views.. etc.)
**Second** if that didn't help much with the performance (very very rare case) you can start thinking about duplicating the information. but that should be your last option, and you need to take all the possible measures to preserve data consistency (using constraints, triggers or whatever).

Answer (score 0):

Duplicating columns will be BAD in terms of space. Assume a situation when you will have huge amount of data in posts model, if you duplicate that, same amount of space will be used again, just to minimize your time. 
Basically you always have to think about the trade off between space and time optimization. 
Try to optimize time by some algorithmic approach like Hash tables, indexing, Binary Search Tree and all. And if you find it still time consuming after certain amount of data space, then think of duplicating data. But remember performance may be increased but space will be utilized more for the same.